# How to use part of a query inside a variable Oracle Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to use a part of a query into a variable , because I have many ifs to prepare the query , but I have not used something like this.

```
FUNCTION f_rel_vendas_importacao(vTP_DADOS in varchar2, nCODIGO in number, dDT_COMPRA_INI in DATE, dDT_COMPRA_FIM in DATE, dDT_EFETIVACAO_INI in DATE, dDT_EFETIVACAO_FIM in DATE) RETURN number is
nRetorno    number(14,2);
vSTRING   VARCHAR2(2000); 

begin

IF vTP_DADOS = 'VL_COMISSAO' THEN
    vSTRING := 'SUM( DECODE( CPF.CD_MOEDA, 1, CPF.VL_COTACAO_UNIT * CPF.QTDE_COMPRA, ( SELECT Imp_Pack.fu_converte_moeda_ORACLE( CPF.CD_MOEDA, 1, CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO, CPF.VL_COTACAO_UNIT, 1) * CPF.QTDE_COMPRA FROM dual )  ) )';   
END IF;

IF vTP_DADOS = 'QTD_VENDA_SELECTCHEMIE_PERIODO' THEN
   vSTRING := 'count(*)';
END IF;

SELECT 
       vSTRING
INTO
    nRetorno
FROM
    COMPRA_PROD_FORN         CPF,
    COMPRA_DATA              CDT
WHERE
    (CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO >= dDT_COMPRA_INI AND CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO <= dDT_COMPRA_FIM) AND
    CDT.CD_COMPRA         = CPF.CD_COMPRA  AND
    CDT.CD_TP_DATA        = 7              AND
    CPF.CD_FORNECEDOR     = nCODIGO;

Return nRetorno;
end
f_rel_vendas_importacao;
```

Comment: When i execute the query i have an error:
EXACT FETCH RETURNS MORE THAN REQUESTED NUMER OF ROWS

But if I use a normal select with these conditions it works

Answer (score 0):

When you SELECT vString, the result is the content of the variable vString. It doesn't make any attempt to interpret that content as a column or expression. You are best off placing those expressions directly into the query.

```
IF vTP_DADOS = 'VL_COMISSAO' THEN
  SELECT 
       SUM( DECODE( CPF.CD_MOEDA, 1, 
          CPF.VL_COTACAO_UNIT * CPF.QTDE_COMPRA, 
            ( SELECT Imp_Pack.fu_converte_moeda_ORACLE( CPF.CD_MOEDA, 1,
                CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO, CPF.VL_COTACAO_UNIT, 1) *
                                         CPF.QTDE_COMPRA 
              FROM dual )  ) )
  INTO
    nRetorno
  FROM
    COMPRA_PROD_FORN         CPF,
    COMPRA_DATA              CDT
  WHERE
    (CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO >= dDT_COMPRA_INI AND 
    CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO <= dDT_COMPRA_FIM) AND
    CDT.CD_COMPRA         = CPF.CD_COMPRA  AND
    CDT.CD_TP_DATA        = 7              AND
    CPF.CD_FORNECEDOR     = nCODIGO;
END IF;

IF vTP_DADOS = 'QTD_VENDA_SELECTCHEMIE_PERIODO' THEN
  SELECT count(*)
  INTO
    nRetorno
  FROM
    COMPRA_PROD_FORN         CPF,
    COMPRA_DATA              CDT
  WHERE
    (CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO >= dDT_COMPRA_INI AND 
    CDT.DT_RECEBIMENTO <= dDT_COMPRA_FIM) AND
    CDT.CD_COMPRA         = CPF.CD_COMPRA  AND
    CDT.CD_TP_DATA        = 7              AND
    CPF.CD_FORNECEDOR     = nCODIGO;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks @gary-myers but but I have 20 or more different options to prepare the select, but the structure after the FROM is always the same, so I would like to know a way to facilitate maintenance and also have less code written since are equal.